# rewrite url .htaccess GET-Parameter for directory routing

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, directory, url-rewriting

I would like to structure my url in the `.htaccess` as follows `https://exmaple.com/index.php?lang=de-DE&path=/dir/subdir/` to `https://example.com/de-DE/dir/subdir/` but keep ability to add additional GET-Parameter.

For the directory i tried this but didn't work out 
`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule /(.+)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Could you please be clear here that you are sending query string directly to url? `https://exmaple.com?lang=de-DE&path=/dir/subdir/` or any php file, kindly do elaborate more here, thank you.

Comment: All related to index.php `https://exmaple.com/index.php?lang=de-DE&path=/dir/subdir/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&path=$2 [L]
```

OR as per OP's comment use QSA flag along with `L` flag to append previously passed query string to newly build one in above rules.